# Connecting ArcSDE via LDAP Authentication

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, authentication

I was wondering if anyone has a sample connection string for SQLPlus using LDAP Authentication?

I am also trying to specify in the connection string the database I wish to use.

Answer (score 1):

This Document is helpful
http://webhelp.esri.com/geoportal_extension/9.3.1/geoportal931_installationguide.pdf
(don't know your configuration setup).

Should be a simple SQL statement with the following parameters: (For Apache Web Server)
Host – the machine name on which the LDAP server was installed.

```
Port– the port number on which the LDAP server is running. Apache Directory Server default is usually 10389 or 19389
protocol – select LDAP v3
DSML Service – leave blank
Base DN – leave blank
Level – select “User + Password”
User DN – the distinguished name (identifier) of the default admin user. Apache Server default is: uid=admin,ou=system
Password – the password to the LDAP server. Apache Server default is: secret
```